# How do I run multiple Ubuntu versions on a single machine?

Tags: system-installation

Is it possible to run two versions of Ubuntu, i.e. 12.04 and 13.10 or 13.04 and 13.10 on the same 32-bit machine?

If it is possible than how can it be done?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Thank goodness you didn't ask [how](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/how-to-install-multiple-linux-distributions-on-a-computer-156038/).

Comment: That link makes no sense, it's from 2004, Ubuntu didn't even exist back then.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch have you ever done this??

Comment: @suhail I've multiboot multiple distros, and 4.10 was October 2004.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch today i tried to install `13.10 lubuntu` on `ubuntu10.04` by creating a seperate partition after beliving in you. But after installation the bootscreen doesn't updated. ie it only shows ubuntu10.04... i wasted lot of time. the problem probably because while installing lubuntu13.10 i changed default boot installation `/dev/sda1` to `/dev/sda3`. did you know how to fix it??

Comment: After reading this post, i belived it is possible and installed. but unable to load it. hmmmm... see my [question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/442358/after-dual-ubuntu-installation-the-boot-screen-doesnt-updated) in askubuntu

Comment: I think the comment of Elliott Frisch is a little bit to old, my GRUB is showing automaticlly all possible ways of booting. I had(since years) never to play aruond with the GRUB convs.

Comment: @suhail You'll need to know your partition scheme, you'll need to manually modify your grub.conf and you'll need to run update-grub. [It](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/multiboot-2-or-more-linux-distros-313616/) [is](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/installation/162044-multibooting-multiple-linux-distros.html) [possible](http://www.hentzenwerke.com/wp/installingmultiplelinuxdistributions_onasinglebox.pdf).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch : you'll just have to run `# update-grub`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily add multiple ext partitions to your disk, then boot a live-CD with whatever linux version you want on it (unetbootin to easily install live-Cd to usb), then when you boot into that live system to install, just choose the new partition you just made for `/` (root). You can use a separate `/home` partition for sharing large data like music,files, videos between installations, and then add multiple smaller root partitions with completely separate operating systems on them (12.04/13.10 etc) so that if you want to get rid of one or replace one with a different version or operating system altogether, your personal files don't get deleted because they are on a separate partition.

Answer (score 3):

**In general**:
 yes, of course!

**How to:**

Your Ubuntu Live-CD-Installer (And a live-stick) will ask you while Installing if you want to install alongside or upgrade, click at 'install alongside' and you got it.

[image: The install shows options to install alongside the existing Ubuntu install, or upgrade it]
Screenshot from [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/03/ubuntu-live-cd-will-let-you-upgrade-to.html)

Answer (score 3):

### Yes. It is possible, I tested it. working fine.

#### [see my question in askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/442358/after-dual-ubuntu-installation-the-boot-screen-doesnt-updated)

After installation of an ubuntu, put the live cd of other ubuntu.

Click option Create partition manually and create a new `ext4` partition (say `/dev/sda3`). gave it mount point `/`.

Now you might have two `ext4` partition. `/dev/sda4` for old ubuntu.`/dev/sda3` for new ubuntu.

#### Note: Never change the boot partition(ie `/dev/sda`)