# After Dual Ubuntu Installation the boot screen doesn't updated?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, lubuntu, bootloader

Today I tried to install **[lubuntu13.10](http://www.lubuntu.net%E2%80%8E)** on ubuntu10.04 by creating a separate partition(`/dev/sda3`).

But after installation the boot screen doesn't updated. ie it only shows ubuntu10.04...

While installing `lubuntu13.10` I changed default boot path from `/dev/sda1` to `/dev/sda3`.

Is that the problem? How to fix it??

### Update 1:

when run `gparted` i got:

[image]

### Update 2:

when i run **`sudo update-grub`**:

```
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (Dialog frontend requires a screen at least 13 
  lines tall and 31 columns wide.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub
Searching for default file ... found: /boot/grub/default
Testing for an existing GRUB menu.lst file ... found: /boot/grub/menu.lst
Searching for splash image ... none found, skipping ...
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-30-generic
Found GRUB 2: /boot/grub/core.img
Found kernel: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Replacing config file /var/run/grub/menu.lst with new version
Updating /boot/grub/menu.lst ... done
```

when i run **`sudo os-prober`** :

```
/dev/sda1:Windows 7 (loader):Windows:chain
/dev/sda3:Ubuntu 13.10 (13.10):Ubuntu:linux
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj I am unable to boot into lubuntu. it only boots to the old `ubuntu10.04`

Comment: Ok, boot into ubuntu 10.04 and then take a screenshot of your gparted.Finally post the image here.

Comment: Now run `sudo update-grub` command on terminal.And also post the output of `sudo os-prober` command

Comment: @AvinashRaj now updated. any idea. i changed to `/dev/sda3` while installation. that is the most probable error. What you think. reinstall and give `/dev/sda` forboot install

Comment: You need to edit "/etc/grub.conf" to include your other Linux partition(s).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch @AvinashRaj I reinstalled lubuntu and provided`/dev/sda` for boot partition. now its working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reinstalled `lubuntu`. and while installation i provided **`/dev/sda`** for boot partition.

### Now its working fine....